# Описание фразы "такого лица"

Tags: семантика, лексика

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, какому описанию соответствует фраза "такого лица" в тексте.

> Досрочное прекращение полномочий лица на выборной должности, прекращение полномочий должностного лица на должности, увольнение, осуществляемое по решению Президента, увольнение военного должностного лица с военной службы в связи с привлечением к ответственности за коррупционное правонарушение, а также отстранение **такого лица** от исполнения служебных полномочий в случаях, предусмотренных ч.1 настоящей статьи, осуществляется с учетом особенностей, определенных Конституцией.
>
> Иные лица, привлеченные к ответственности за коррупционные правонарушения, подлежат увольнению с соответствующих должностей в 3-х дневный срок со дня получения органом копии соответствующего судебного решения.»

"Такое лицо" - это

1. лица, привлеченные к ответственности,
2. лица на перечисленных должностях,
3. 1 и 2 вместе.

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь нечеткость в формулировке.
"Такое лицо" в данном контексте может быть: 
а) лицо на выборной должности, должностное лицо на должности, военное должностного лицо - т.е. лицо подпадающее хотя бы под одно из названных определений.
б) только военное должностное лицо.

Скорее всего - по практике чтения подобных документов - могу сказать, что вернее всего более широкое понимание, т.е. вариант а).
Как вы верно заметили, как "лицо, совершившее преступление" трактоваться подобная формулировка не может просто по грамматическим соображениям. Оборот "в связи с cовершением преступления" не отвечает на вопрос "какое (лицо)?".

Comment: спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в таких случаях обобщение относится ко всему тому, что было перечислено выше.

Comment: а относить ли фразу:
"в связи с привлечением к ответственности за коррупционное правонарушение" и к "такому лицу", это ведь не описание перечисляемых лиц, а сопутствующие события?